# Transpose input matrix before LinearRegression in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Here is my python program:

```
import numpy as np
from  sklearn import linear_model

X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T**2
y=np.array([1, 4, 16])
model=linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
```

As a result i have:

```
Coefficients: 
[1.]
```

It is a first program i test with sklearn.
My question is: why i have to use the transpose .T**2 in the third instruction ?
Without

```
T**2
```

i have these errors https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8T07.jpg 
i use http://jupyter.org/try

Comment: The transpose is needed to have an X matrix with shape (number_of_samples, number_of_x_dimensions).

Comment: @Learningisamess what mean please **2  ?

Comment: I guess that in this specific case you are fitting `y` as a linear function of `x^2` and not a linear function of `x`. I advise you to look at feature engineering in machine learning if this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation says](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit), you have to pass a matrix with n_samples (3) and n_features (1). So your input X in the form [[1,2,3]] needs the inner vector in a vertical position.
After **T:

```
array([[ 1],
       [ 4],
       [16]])
```

This is what happens under the hood: https://machinelearningmastery.com/solve-linear-regression-using-linear-algebra/

Comment: X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T**2
print(X)   -->  i have [[ 1]
 [ 4]
 [16]]           i want to keep the vector X unchanged ?

Comment: a linear relation i.e y=a*x+b that's it ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write "NON" in front of Linear. Your second question it's not related to the question itself, maybe you should consider opening a different Q.
Anyway, your data are describing a curve then a Linear model will fail to explain this behavior.

Comment: i have changed the vector Y    https://imgur.com/a/dceoJ7O     so i have y=ax+b  --> y=6*x+1   --> the program give me the coefficient "a=6" only ! how can i get the second parameter (b=1)? Kind regards.

Comment: It's intecept_, also provided in the documentation  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Comment: print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)

Answer (score 0):

You have to match `X,y` in same dimensions (same number of training samples)

If you do not use transpose, you have 1 training sample `[1,2,4]` but 3 labels, which does not match

If you use transpose, you could have `[1][2][4]` 3 samples and thus could match 3 labels

the `**2` does not matters

Answer (score 0):

The initial shape of matrix X in (1,3). You need to pass the matrix in form of (3,1) as the documentation [says](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) and mentioned in answer by Alessandro

The **2 part is just squaring each of the element of matrix X. You can run it without that part. The coefficient will differ then. Currently, when you squared, you have each of the X and y values as (1,1), (4,4) and (16,16) so the coefficient (slope of equation y=mx+ c, if you plot these on graph) is 1. If you don't square, coefficient will differ accordingly